# I want to change to hot key(s) for spaces

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, spaces

Currently I can switch between spaces using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>. I want to change that to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences, open Exposé and Spaces, and go to the Spaces tab. Click the menu by "To switch between spaces:" and choose the second option.

[image: Image showing location of menu]

Answer (score 1):

go to `System Preferences -> expose & Spaces`

[image]

Then select desire keyboard shortcut from "To Switch  between spaces"

Comment: oh duh, thank you for stating out the obvious i apparently over looked :P